# FPGA image processing

Tags: fpga

I am doing a project( with Zynq 7000 kit from Xilinx) in which I need to receive an image from an Arm microcontroller and deliver it to an FPGA . I do not know how FPGA receive an image.

Should I convert image to an array or text file ? ( even without an ARM microcontroller here, I do not know how I can load an image ( like bitmap image or DICOM image) onto FPGA)

The important point is that I need some code that can  synthesized.

I can not use some thing like "fileopen" or anything.

Is it possible to mail me a code for doing this part? May i  know if you have explain sth about this question in your site.

Comment: Is the ARM microcontroller you refer to here the Cortex A9 inside the Zynq or is it separate physical device?  If they're separate devices you should describe how the ARM and the Zynq are physically connected.

Comment: yes! it is the cortex A9 inside Zynq!

Answer (score 4):

You define the protocol yourself.

The ARM and the FPGA will have some connection, e.g. some GPIO pins from the ARM connected to some GPIO pins on the FPGA. On top of that, you will have to define a protocol, typically like this:

1. Symbol transport

   Your protocol needs to transport data symbols from one side to the other. A symbol can be a single bit, a nibble, a byte or something else (it is up to you to optimize here). The recipient must be able to find out whether the current state of the signals is a transition state, or a symbol that should be read.

   A simple implementation is the SPI protocol, which has separate data and clock connections. When a rising edge on the clock pin is detected, a single data bit is read. The bus can be stopped by stopping the clock, and the speed dynamically adjusted.
2. Lower Layer Framing

   On top of the symbol transport, you usually want some kind of grouping, for example, a convention that you always transport whole bytes together, and have a pause after each frame, or that you always send a length indicator first.

   This is important when the sender and the receiver lose synchronisation, e.g. because there is a short pulse on the clock line because of interference, and the receiver from that point on has counted one bit more than the sender.

   When the pause starts, the receiver will have one bit too many, which is a clear sign that something went wrong, so the receiver can then reset and restart at zero.

   On this layer, you can also include an indication which stream this frame belongs to, giving you the opportunity to split data and command traffic.
3. Error correction

   Usually, these frames are extended with an error checking code (e.g. a CRC), which allows discarding data that has been transmitted with an error. A feedback mechanism can then be used to retransmit data that has been garbled. A possible implementation is that a single line is asserted when a frame has been received correctly; the sender can continue with the next frame when it sees the acknowledgement, or repeats the last frame after a timeout.
4. Upper Layer Framing

   On top of that, you'd then have the actual data.

   If you have a separate command stream, you can use that for framing (i.e. have a command "start of image", followed by data on the data stream, followed by the "end of image" command).

   When everything is inside a single stream, you should follow a pattern of sync-tag-length-data. Every upper layer frame starts with a known sequence; if that is missing, data is discarded until that sequence is found (again, resynchronisation). The tag then performs the split into data and command streams, the length shows how much data is to follow, and the scan for the sync pattern is restarted after the data has been processed.

It is possible to combine the layers to optimize, or to skimp on error checking if errors in the output are acceptable and you want to push for performance. Also, I'd check if the pins on the ARM side have a "special function" attached to them, as most embedded CPUs have ready-made controllers for several communication protocols, which will allow you to implement the protocol quicker, and use hardware like the DMA controller for better performance.

Comment: well, thanks. But I still do not understand how the format of "the symbols" you mentioned above must be. for example if I convert a bitmap image to a .txt file (using matlab) how can I read the .txt file? knowing that the method must be able to synthesize.

Comment: Good answer, however note that since the OP mentions Zynq it's quite likely that the ARM and FPGA are on the same die connected by AXI4 interconnect.  This makes life much easier - just DMA the binary data into a BRAM

Comment: yeah! exactly! ARM and FPGA are connected via AXI bus. what format is the best for ARM to save image in that format and deliver it to FPGA? Is an array of pixels efficient?

Comment: @fatemeh it depends on what you want to do with the data on the FPGA?  Assuming you want to perform some kind of processing on the FPGA itself then you're best off picking a data format well suited to the FPGA logic.  Typically this will be raw binary pixel data (either RGB or YPbPr).

Comment: @ Chiggs . I want to implement an edge detection filter on the image on FPGA. and the image is not binary. it is grayscale. ( having more than 2 levels). now you mean these two formats (either RGB or YPbPr) can be used for saving data and deliver it to fpga? (as I know these formats are used in video and not image. can image be saved in this format)

Comment: @fatemeh by binary I meant as opposed to a text file or some other format.  You also are unlikely to want any compression like JPEG, rather the "raw" binary data.  You might be better off designing the FPGA side of you project first - the RTL will define how the software interface should behave and what format you need the data in.

Comment: If you have RGB, use `Y = (R*0.3 + G*0.6 + B*0.1)` to turn it to grayscale. If you have YPbPr, just throw away Pb and Pr.